# How to retrieve $_POST variable in an action

Tags: zend-framework, post, zend-http-client

I am very newbie in zend framework,
I send some data to an action with post method by this way:

```
$config = array(
    'adapter'   => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
);

$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://example.com/api/last-news', $config);
$client->setParameterPost('name' ,'value');
$dataresult = $client->request('POST')->getBody();
```

when In `lastNewsAction()` action in `ApiController.php` I use `var_dump($_POST)` it's passed me empty array, but when I send those data to  a simple file out of framework(something like http://example.com/test.php) the `$_POST` has correct value. SO How can I retrieve `$_POST` variable in an action?

Comment: Usually `$this->getRequest()->getParam('var-name');` works

Comment: If your action is returning a NULL value for the $_Request object then the data is not getting to the action. Check and make sure your urls are valid and correct. Unless you have redefined your routes the url you are trying to reach would be the *ApiController* and *lastNewsAction*. That's your starting place. POST anything, just to make sure the route works.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want them all...

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {        
    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    ...
```

Comment: when I var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost()) it returns array(0){}.

Comment: and also var_dump($this->getRequest()->isPost()) returns bool(false).

Comment: Well you are not getting a POST then.  What does the super global $_REQUEST show?  Use a tool like HTTP Headers browser extension to see what's going on.

Comment: Your API controller simply extends `Zend_Controller_Action`?  Your not doing something with `Zend_Rest_Route` or something?  Need to understand better how you are handling the request to suggest where you might be unsetting the _POST.

Comment: $_REQUESt is null, too...
I test with HTTP RESOUCE tool(firefox extension) , nothing happend.
API Controller exteds from Zend_Controller_Action, let met check Zend_Rest_Route...

Comment: I'm not found Zend_Rest_Route anywhere in project.

Comment: Really sounds then like its on the client end.  If for example  `var_dump($_POST);` in your app's index.php file is empty you are certainly not successfully posting.  Might be due to a redirect.  Perhaps check the 'strictredirects' setting for the `Zend_Http_Client`.

Comment: in index.php `$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://example.com/index.php', $config)` its returns $_POST variable correctly, but `$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://example.com/api/last-news', $config)` doesnt work.
I check it hasn't any redirect from http://example.com/api/last-news...